# Graphs, Hamiltonian graphs, nodes... don't know topic name

Tags: graph-theory

I've got an exam in a couple of hours and going over the questions on a past paper. If someone could check out my answer, i'd be extremely grateful.

[image]

[image]

Comment: a,b,d,e,c is a Hamiltonian **path**. It is not a **cycle** because it doesn't return to its starting point. There can't be a Hamiltonian cycle in this graph, because there is no escape from c.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to write any proof to a iii. it's alright.

EDIT:
As bof comments, there is **Hamilton Path**, and no **Hamilton Cycle** (because there is no way out from C)

Comment: what proof could i write :O im simply showing the diagram?

Comment: You're right, my bad. I'm making some proofs with Hamilton paths now so when I see 'Hamilton cycle' it makes me determined to write some proof :)

Comment: :P Ah ok, do you know what the difference is between hamilton path and hamilton cycle btw?

Comment: Oh ok, so so there is **no** Hamilton Cycle, there is only Hamilton Path.

Comment: Nope i mean like a definition of the difference between them :P cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct according to me . I haven't found any error in your answer . have a good score in your exam .